# CSS Vertical Center with dynamic divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a div called container that I'm trying to vertically center. I've got it vertically centered, but now I'm adding divs to it via jQuery, like:

```
$("#add").on("click", function () {
    $(".elements").append("<div class='element'>World</div>");
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CDk4E/

What the problem is:

If you haven't added any divs yet, the page looks good (it's vertically centered). But if you start adding div's, the `.element` div that contains "Hello" gets pushed to the top. But what I'd really like to do is instead have it be kept in it's original spot, and have the other `.element` divs be just added on to the bottom.

EDIT:
Also, the first element is always a fixed size.

Comment: does the first element have a fixed height?

Comment: @web-tiki, Yes it does. I'll put that in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add *padding:50%;* to your .container

```
<style>
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: table;
}
.container {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top:50%;
    border:1px red dashed;
    position:relative;
}

.element{
    background:purple;
    color:#FFF;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
}

</style>
```

Here is outcome: http://jsfiddle.net/CDk4E/2/